# Deadlock questions (OS related)

Tags: resources, deadlock

Consider a computer with five individual resources name R1 …. R5. Let five processes P1, …. P5 make requests in order, as follows:

```
i. P1 requests R2
ii. P4 requests R3
iii. P3 requests R1
iv. P2 requests R4
v. P5 requests R5
vi. P4 requests R2
vii. P5 requests R3
viii. P3 requests R5
```

Assume Process P_i gets R_i if R_i is currently available.

Is there deadlock and if so at what point did it occur and which processes did it involve?

Can anyone please help me out? For the first one I was thinking there's no deadlock, but I'm not sure how to prove.

Thanks!

Comment: not homework. I revised it. please take a look!

Comment: You would need more information. Like, what OS is this, how are the processes scheduled, how are the resources locked, what options do the processes have to take locks, do they try locks or do they wait, are the processes dependent on each other (e.g., does P1 need to wait for P4 to do something while still holding R2's lock, etc.)

Comment: Jason, you don't need _any_ more information. The sequence of events is quite clear from the question.

Comment: @paxdiablo I disagree. We don't know enough about the processes or what they're doing. If P1 takes the lock for R2 and then goes on to _do things_ and then waits on P4 while it's already trapped on R2 you have a deadlock. More information is absolutely required to state with certainty that there is no potential for deadlock.

Comment: No, the sequence is all that matters and that's fully specified. How much time is spent doing things is irrelevant. The timings of operations is actually _restricted_ by the sequence since (for example) if P2 spent too long doing something compared to P1, P1 would be able to get a resource _first!_. If that were the case, the sequence may be different but it's not, so that _isn't_ the case :-)

Comment: @paxdiablo The sequence isn't all that matters, unless you state that the only thing process P_i ever does is acquire a resource, use that resource and no other resource and then relinquish the resource and that each process P_i is completely serial in nature. In that case, yes, all that matters is the sequence. If those processes do anything else or are in any way interdependent while they hold said resources, a deadlock most certainly can ensue. All we know is that P4 won't ask for R2 until P1 has asked for it, but we have no idea what else P1 does in the mean time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that's the actual sequence of events, there is no deadlock there. Initially, all resources are free, Running that code in sequence:

```
1. P1 requests R2: p1 has r2.
2. P4 requests R3: p4 has r3.
3. P3 requests R1: p3 has r1.
4. P2 requests R4: p2 has r4.
5. P5 requests R5: p5 has r5.
6. P4 requests R2: p4 has r3, awaiting r2(p1).
7. P5 requests R3: p5 has r5, awaiting r3(p4).
8. P3 requests R5: p3 has r1, awaiting r5(p5).
```

So the current state is:

```
p1 has r2.
p2 has r4.
p3 has r1, awaiting r5(p5).
p4 has r3, awaiting r2(p1).
p5 has r5, awaiting r3(p4).
```

and the chain of waits is (waiter -> blocker):

```
p4 -> p1, p5 -> p4, p3 -> p5
```

or:

```
p3 -> p5 -> p4 -> p1
```

Because there is no cycle in there, deadlock has not happened.

Further proof can be obtained by simply having the non-waiters releasing their resources and following the chain of events:

```
 9. p1 releases r2, frees it up for p4 (p3 and p5 blocked, p4 has r3/r2).
10. p4 releases r3, frees it up for p5 (p3 blocked, p5 has r5/r3).
11. p5 releases r5, frees it up for p3 (nobody is blocked, p3 has r5).
```

Final state after those steps is that:

```
p1 has nothing.
p2 has r4.
p3 has r1/r5.
p4 has r2.
p5 has r3.
```

Now there are no blockages and each thread can simply release whatever resources they still have allocated.

---

Now, were you to expand your question to ask if deadlock were possible if those operations could happen in any order (while maintaining order within each thread), the answer is still no.

It's a basic tenet of mult-threading that you can avoid deadlock by ensuring all your resources are allocated in the same order in every thread. From the operations you gave, the individual threads allocate their resources as follows (order must be maintained *within* a thread):

```
P1: R2
P2: R4
P3: R1 R5
P4: R3 R2
P5: R5 R3
```

So, how can we ensure they're all allocating in the same sequence? We just need to find a sequence that matches. First, we start with the above list but add spaces so that like resources are lined up and no resource is on both sides of another resource:

```
P1:             R2
P2: R4
P3:    R1 R5
P4:          R3 R2
P5:       R5 R3

    R4 R1 R5 R3 R2  <==
```

And there's your sequence. *Every* thread is allocating resources in the order 4, 1, 5, 3, 2. Not every thread allocates every resource but that's irrelevant here.

That's also not the only solution (R4 is stand-alone so it could go *anywhere* in the list - every other resource is involved in a single dependency chain (1,5,3,2) so their relative positions are fixed).

However, it's sufficient to prove that every thread is allocating the resources in a specific order, hence deadlock is impossible.

Comment: If the downvoter would like to explain where they think my reasoning is incorrect, I'd be happy to set them straight :-) Steps 9, 10 and 11 prove this beyond doubt.

Comment: Thanks, I see now. But what if instead P1 now requests R1? Say, as the 9th request? Is the system still safe? Is there deadlock? This is informative!

Comment: @Cybershot, that's a whole _different_ question. The answer, BTW, is yes, you're deadlocked: the wait chain is `p3>p5>p4>p1>p3>p5...` ad infinitum. Perhaps you might want to ask in another question if deadlock is possible if the threads can run in _any_ order then just specify what each thread does in sequence.

Comment: Yes, I see that. How would we solved this deadlock using the Banker's algorithm? Let's say it's applied to the first five requests? How would the resources be allocated at the end of the five requests?

Comment: @Cyber, questions shouldn't be asked in comment boxes for the simple reason that you don't get as much exposure. If you want to know how to solve that, then you should ask another question with the salient details. That way, rather than just asking me and possibly five other bods who may be watching this question, you can call on the entire user base of SO.

Comment: @Cyber, I've added further information for the case where threads may intermix their operations in any order (though order must be maintained within the thread of course). Bottom line, still no deadlock. Hopefully, the processes followed will help you out with any combination of resources though it's likely to become unmanageable as the number of resources increase. Still, if you can guarantee every thread allocates in the same order, there will be no problems.

Comment: He seems to have forgotten his downvote though. Don't worry, +1